# How to use driver.startActivity on IOS?

Tags: java, ios, android-activity, driver, appium

Hi I was building some tests for Android and now I want to run the same tests on IOS. Sometimes in my code I have to open google chrome then go back and launch the app, for that I use

```
driver.startActivity("com.consul.android.smartbeer.staging", "com.whirlpool.ted.View.SplashActivity");
```

and

```
driver.startActivity("com.android.chrome", "com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main");
```

**My question is:**

how can I use a similar command for IOS? I know that it has `driver.launchApp();` but If I insert the `Bundle_Name` it doesn’t work. Is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

To get quiet the same functionality for iOS with Appium you might look into using **deep links**:

`driver.get('deep_link_url')`

It allows navigating directly to appropriate screen of your iOS app.

However:

- deep links should be implemented in your iOS application
- it works **only for Simulators** at the moment.

You can track progress on getting it work with real devices [here](https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/9066)